how the log can auto delete when 24 hour in sentry.io?
while in offline mode the error log in the indexed db, i want to auto delete when the log in indexed db more than 2 hour or more..
this is the code :
const app = createApp(App)

Sentry.init({
    app,
    dsn: "DSN_TOKEN",
    logErrors : true,
    release: __SENTRY_RELEASE__,
    transport: Sentry.makeBrowserOfflineTransport(Sentry.makeFetchTransport),
    transportOptions: {
      // Caching options, e.g. maxQueueSize.
      
    },
    integrations: [
      new Integrations.BrowserTracing({
        routingInstrumentation: Sentry.vueRouterInstrumentation(router),
        tracingOrigins: ["localhost", "my-site-url.com",/^\//],
      }),
    ],
    // Performance Monitoring
    // Performance Monitoring
    // Performance Monitoring
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0, //  Capture 100% of the transactions

});






as custom solution you can use indexeddb functions or library to delete old sentry records.  I believe sentry records include timestamps you can check against.  only problem is there's no way to run some function automatically as soon as timestamp is 24 hours old.  you need to pick some other method of checking the db, e.g. on app creation, or when new record is being created.
